# Dynamic data load on ASPX page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an internal web service (ASP.NET) written on C# in a company I work for. There are only 2 pages in it, one of this pages contains DropDownList. 
Every time when user selecting an item from that DropDownList I need to somehow pass selected item value to a static method and show result string of that method anywhere on page.

I've never worked with ASP.NET or any web programming before and a bit confused about how to do it, not sure where to start looking even.

Comment: Also you will have to make the method as protected as mentioned by Blachshma below as you won't be able to call a static method.

Answer (score 1):

In your aspx file you should have this:

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
```

Notice the **AutoPostBack="True"** which goes back to the server and fires the selectedindexchanged event immediately after the user changes the selection in the listbox

In your code-behind (.cs file)
You should have this:

```
 protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Call static method and pass the ListBox1.SelectedIndex
        // MyStaticMethod(ListBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }
```

Comment: Then it seems that you're using ASP.NET MVC, which is different from the basic ASP.NET and has a different syntax . I recommend either updating this question or create a new question in which you make a more distinctive title, keywords and code samples.

Answer (score 0):

you can either se5t the autoPostBack="true" and handle the change event on the server side or using jQuery subscribe for the change event and get the value on the client side

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check out some of the great resources that microsoft provides for new .NET developers. They will be really helpful in getting you started. Her is a link of some really good videos to help you out: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos

Not sure what language you are coming from, if any... But for the most part webforms is going to work a lot like other web based methodologies.

Your ASP.NET Controls (in your case the DropDownList) have both client and server side events.

You will probably want to map the server-side OnSelectedIndexChanged event on your DropDownList.

In order to cause a postback on that control you will want to set the AutoPostBack property to true on your DropDownList.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

In html ,

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

In aspx.cs page,,

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selctedValue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        /// Call yours static methid here
     YourMethod(selctedValue);
}
```